# update price Observer is not working on cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, event-observer

Here is the modules config file: app\etc\modules\Cart_Updates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
       <Cart_Updates>
         <codePool>local</codePool>
         <active>true</active>
       </Cart_Updates>
    </modules>
  </config>
```

Here is my config file : in app\code\local\Cart\Updates\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
   <modules>
     <Cart_Updates>
       <version>1.0.1</version>
     </Cart_Updates>
   </modules>
   <global>
       <models>
         <Cart_Updates>
           <class>Cart_Updates_Model</class>
         </Cart_Updates>
       </models>
       <events>
          <sales_quote_add_item>
              <observers>
                 <cart_updates_model_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Cart_Updates_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>updatePrice</method>
                 </cart_updates_model_observer>
             </observers>
          </sales_quote_add_item>
      </events>
  </global>
 </config>
```

And here is the Observer: in app\code\local\Cart\Updates\Model\Observer.php

```
<?php

    class Cart_Updates_Model_Observer {

      public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        //exit;
      $order = Mage::registry('current_order'); //For getting current order 
      echo $orderid = $order->getRealOrderId(); // For getting orderid
      $quote_item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
      $payment = 30; //add your custom product price here and do your logic here
      $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($payment);
      $quote_item->save();
      return $this;
      }
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to update your cart item price on cart update?

Comment: i want to set the custom price when product will be added to the cart, it will show custom price that we will set in the observer and over ride the original one

Answer (score 2):

here is code for updting the custom price

use this event `checkout_cart_product_add_after`

for current event

```
  $item->setCustomPrice($customprice);
  $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customprice);
  $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

other method

```
   $product_id = $item->getProductId();
   $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id); 
   $item= Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($item->getId());
   $payment = 30;
   $item->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId());
   $item->setCustomPrice($payment);
   $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($payment);
   $item->setProduct($product);  
   $item->save();
```

Comment: Not working bro.

Comment: i think it is not triggering the Observer. i have added die; top of the function its not doing any thing.

Comment: use  `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event

Comment: It is not working for me Bro..

Comment: @Xabby change method name to `updatePrice` as you declare in config.xml

Comment: @QaisarSatti, can we set the custom tax_amount also like custom price for the quote item? here is my question,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274520/how-to-set-custom-tax-price-during-add-to-cart